# Is there any built-in functionality we can use to share the charts on social media platform in Amcharts 4

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

Do Amcharts provide functionality to share the chart image on social media platform ?

Comment: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/exporting/ ?

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes the doc you have provided is about how to export on local machine, i want to export it on whatsapp or linkedin